# Xamarin or Phonegap - taking photo with integrated camera

Tags: cordova, xamarin

I think I may know the answer to this but:

I am building an app that requires the user to take a photo.  The client would like the photo to be taken from within the applications interface, so their branding stays in place and they get to use a custom shutter icon etc.

I am evaluating PhoneGap and Xamarin, but so far I can only find how to launch the devices default camera app and get the photo back from there.

Looking around a lot off applications do it using the deault camera app, so I am guesing what I am looking for might be beyond these frameworks like Xamarin and Phone Gap.

So is there a way to do what the client wants if we are not building natively?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin app is a native app and what you can do from ObjC you can do from C# with Xamarin. Attaching the video capture to a UIView is quite simple and one way is to use [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Create a new project and copy this to the view controllers ViewDidLoad method and you should get a video overlay with a button on it:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var captureSession = new MonoTouch.AVFoundation.AVCaptureSession();
    var previewLayer = new MonoTouch.AVFoundation.AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(captureSession)
    {
            LayerVideoGravity = MonoTouch.AVFoundation.AVLayerVideoGravity.ResizeAspectFill,
            Frame = this.View.Bounds
    };
    var device = MonoTouch.AVFoundation.AVCaptureDevice.DefaultDeviceWithMediaType(
                     MonoTouch.AVFoundation.AVMediaType.Video);

    NSError error;

    var input = new MonoTouch.AVFoundation.AVCaptureDeviceInput(device, out error);

    captureSession.AddInput(input);

    this.View.Layer.AddSublayer(previewLayer);

    var button = new UIButton(new RectangleF(0, 0, this.View.Bounds.Width, 100));

    button.SetTitle("My button", UIControlState.Normal);

    button.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => 
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Take a still picture here");
        };

    this.View.Add(button);

    captureSession.StartRunning();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin does not use the "default camera app" to take pictures - you can stay within your app - but by default it does use the standard iOS Camera controls.  If you want to customize them you can.  This [sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/SharedResources) from Xamarin uses a custom overlay (I haven't tried it, I'm relying on the comments)